Correct way to persist User with Firebase in Expo React Native
So I am building a Mobile app with Expo, React-Native and Firebase. I wanted to persist the state of my users. If my user is present then i want him to get redirected to my home screen else i want him to stay on the login screen. So how to do it in Expo React Native applications using Firebase?
I am using expo-router as well as react-native-async-storage.
Dependencies versions:
"expo": "~51.0.35",
"firebase": "^10.11.0",
"react-native": "0.74.5",
"expo-router": "~3.5.23",


firebase.js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage),
});
const db = getFirestore();

export { app, auth, db };

_layout.js
const router = useRouter();
useEffect(() => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      console.log("User: ", user);
      if (user) {
            router.push("home");
          }  
       else {
        console.log("You are not signed in");
        router.push("auth");
      }
    });
    
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [router]);

I don't know if the above mentioned is the correct way to persist the user stat, but its not working as expected.

As firebase takes some time to initialize and figure out if the user is authenticated , I want to show an Activity Indicator for that time.
This method gives errors when i log out and refresh my app it keeps me on the Activity Indicator and doesn't update anything.
When should the onAuthStateChanged function be present if we are using expo-router. Should we store it in one of our screens or in the _layout.js file

I would really appreciate if someone would explain the complete process of authenticating and maintaining user persistence while maintaining the UX.
